# How to use riverpod for future without run app

Tags: flutter, dart, http, future, riverpod

I am developing an app with flutter and I am using flutter_riverpod package. I am very new in flutter_riverpod.

I have a page which getting datas from database. The datas are article datas.
I have 3 .dart file for this process. I have a lot of files but but for that process ı have only 3)

1. AAmain.dart file.
2. AAx2.dart file.
3. AAapi.dart file

The AAmain.dart file is my first page of app. This page shows all article as a list in listview. with http call but no problem for getting datas or writing for listview.

The AAx2.dart file is my second page of app. This page shows only 1 article details. for instance article image, article title, article concent etc.

The AAapi.dart file is not a page of app. It is only a function which has a fetch 1 article details from server(with http).

My purpose is click item AAmain.dart page and go AAx2.dart page with bring 1 data and fetch datas for 1 article.
But I don't know send datas between pages. I can send AAmain.dart to x2.dart file. But I can't send to AAapi.dart. Because AAapi.dart has no providerscope or ref or widgetref. I don't understand here.

I used to use getx package for send datas between pages with arguments but now I am using flutter_riverpod but I can't understand.
This issue is so important for me thanks for all helps.

I simplified my codes to has an easy understand.(But only ui codes).

AAmain.dart file

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'wp-api.dart';
import 'AAx2.dart';
import 'package:flutter_eem_1/custom.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: benimApp0()));
}

class benimApp0 extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: xMyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class xMyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                future: fetchWpPosts(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 5,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(createRoute1());
                            final aVider = StateProvider(
                                (_) => snapshot.data![index]["slug"]);

                            //  Get.toNamed("/home",
                            //      arguments: snapshot.data![index]["slug"]);
                          },
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Image.network(
                                  snapshot.data![index]["featured_image"]
                                          ["large"]
                                      .toString(),
                                ),
                              ),              
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  return Container();
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

AAx2.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_eem_1/singlewp-api.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_eem_1/AAapi.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: benimApp1()));
}

class benimApp1 extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: x2(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class x2 extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                  future: fetch1WpPosts(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            snapshot.data![0]["title"],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Image.network(
                                snapshot.data![0]["featured_image_large"]),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                    return Container();
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

AAapi.dart file

```
              import 'package:flutter_eem_1/riverpodTry1.dart';
              import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
              import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
              import 'dart:convert';
              import 'AAx2.dart';
              import 'AAmain.dart';

Future<List<dynamic>> fetch_1WpPosts() async {
    final String data1 = ref.watch(aVider);
  
  var x = 'https://meshcurrent.online/wp/wp-json/api/v1/posts/';
  var y = data1;
  var z = '$x$y';

  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(z));
  List<dynamic> convertDataJson = jsonDecode(response.body);

  return convertDataJson;
}
```

the problem is ref in future AAapi.dart file.

Comment: Please name your files and symbols in accordance with the style guidelines.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding somewhere - I don't think Riverpod is a navigation library that allows you to pass data around pages.